# Emacs regex: add quote in middle of line

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm trying to build up an sql statement, but need to have my VARCHAR fields quoted, of course. So far Emacs regex (with wonderful re-builder) has got me this far:

```
('0D69B2','Pool Chem Room,'B69E08','Spaces'),                                                                                                                     
('113243','Weight Room,'B69E08','Spaces'),                                                                                                                        
('175118','Custodial Closet 3,'B69E08','Spaces'),                                                                                                                 
('1BAA68','Life Fitness,'B69E08','Spaces'),
```

but right before the second comma, I need to insert another single quote. Normal regex has me identify the blob

```
^('\\w+','\\w+
```

then refer to it as a group \1 then sub in the group with the '

Good, but my problem is I can't figure out how to get more than the first word of the second field (after the first comma). I need to get all the way over to just before the second comma, then identify it as a group, then sub in group with added '. Right? Or am I going at this all wrong?

Comment: If you will never ever have a comma in the middle of the string, then try `[^,]+` instead of the second `\\w+`.

Comment: My re-builder window has "^('\\w+','[^,]+" and it's matching perfectly. Thanks Zack. But I'm doing something wrong with query-replace-regex because M-x query-replace-regexp RET ^('\\w+','[^,]+ RET \1' is not doing it. I want the ^('\\w+','[^,]+ group to stay and add the ' to it on the end.

Comment: Change `\1` to `\&` in the replacement and it should work.  If it doesn't, put `\(` ... `\)` around the entire regexp and then `\1` should work in the replacement.

Comment: This elisp kludge worked: `(while (re-search-forward "\\(^('\\w+','[^,]+\\),\\('[^)]+),\\)" nil t)                                                                                           
       (replace-match "\\1',\\2"))`  although my second group could have been done better. But still couldn't get it to work in the mini-buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluationg the progn-form should display the result:

```
(progn (re-search-forward "\(\\('[[:alnum:] ]+',\\)\\('[[:alnum:] ]+\\)\\(,'[[:alnum:] ]+','[[:alnum:] ]+'\\)")
```

(message "%s" (concat (match-string-no-properties 1)(match-string-no-properties 2) "'" (match-string-no-properties 3))))

('0D69B2','Pool Chem Room,'B69E08','Spaces'),